# How to check if role has a privilege on Oracle object?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to know if a role has a privilege on Oracle object.

I wrote the following function :

```
create or replace  FUNCTION HasPrivilegeOnObject
     (RoleName in varchar2
       , ObjectName in varchar2
       , ObjectOwner in varchar2
       , PrivilegeName in varchar2) 
    RETURN NUMBER 
AS
    Output number;
BEGIN       

    select count(*) into Output 
    from DBA_TAB_PRIVS        
    where 
            GRANTEE = RoleName and
            OWNER = ObjectOwner and
            TABLE_NAME = ObjectName and
            Privilege = PrivilegeName;                   

    if Output > 0 then                
            Output := 1;        
    end if;  

    return Output;
END HasPrivilegeOnObject;
```

The functions compiles but, when I execute it, It doesn't return the right result.

For a certain role and an object, when I check the value of the variable Output **INSIDE** the function, it's at **1**. But When I check it from another function, it's **0**.

Summary :

```
call dbms_output.put_line(HasPrivilegeOnObject(Role1, Table1, User1, 'SELECT'))
```

returns 1 ;

In another PL/SQL Function :

```
HasPrivilegeOnObject(Role1, Table1, User1, 'SELECT')
```

returns 0.

Does anyone have an idea about this problem ?

Comment: What arr the exact parameter values?

Comment: SQl>set role none; SQL>call dbms.... What's the output now?